# Can I check a type against a union type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do an "instanceof"-like query on an object against a union type that's built into the language?

I have a type alias with a union type as follows:

```
type MyType = Foo | Bar | Thing;
```

Each of `Foo`, `Bar` and `Thing` inherit from `Base`

```
class Base { /* ... */ }
class Foo extends Base { /* ... */ }
class Bar extends Base { /* ... */ }
class Thing extends Base { /* ... */ }
```

Some method returns a `Base`.

```
function getBase(): Base { /* ... */ return base; }
```

Ideally, I would like to create another method that can return a `MyType` after calling `getBase()`

```
function getMyType(): MyType { 
    var item = getBase();
    if (item instanceof MyType)
        return item;
    else
        return null;
}
```

If `MyType` were not a type alias, the above code would work.  However, since it is a type alias, it doesn't seem to work.  So to re-iterate my question, is something of this nature built into the language?

Clearly, what I want can be accomplished by checking the instanceof query against each individual class:

```
function getMyType(): MyType { 
    var item = getBase();
    if (item instanceof Foo || item instanceof Bar || item instanceof Thing)
        return item;
    else
        return null;
}
```

But this is hardly ideal; if some future developer wanted to create `OtherThing` and extend `MyType` to also include this new class, then hopefully  remembered to update `getMyType()`.

**Is there a feature built into the language to address this, or is there potentially a better way of doing this?**

Comment: Regarding "better way," maybe there is a way to iterate over the different classes included in a union type alias.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no runtime representation of type aliases, so there's nothing "built in" per se for doing this kind of check.

This pattern would be fairly maintainable, though:

```
// Future devs: Please keep these in sync
type MyType       =  Foo|Bar|Thing;
let MyTypeClasses = [Foo,Bar,Thing];

function getMyType(): MyType { 
    var item = getBase();
    if (MyTypeClasses.some(c => item instanceof c))
        return item;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Surely not perfect, but reasonable.

Comment: This doesnt compile for me - since it seems to be using classes as values?

Comment: Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I totally miss something like (status instanceof ("ok" | "noOk"))

Answer (score 63):

If you knew some specific key for an interested Type you can do it via `in` operator:

```
function move(pet: Fish | Bird) {
  if ("swim" in pet) {
    return pet.swim(); //pet is Fish
  }
  return pet.fly(); //pet is Bird
}
```

As for me much easier than an additional function with stuff.
That what I was looking for.

[Docs.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator)

Comment: CAUTION: after compiling to js, if the property name is minified, then the `in` operator will break.  Nasty "Heisenbug"—the code works fine in debug mode.

Comment: @PeterDavis how would you go about it for this to be "heisenbug" proof?

Comment: would `if(pet.swim !== undefined)` be enough? you can access one level of undefined attributes (or more using `?.`) so this _should_ work

Comment: @PeterDavis I find this kinda hard to believe, as the [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#in) operator does come from native JS! TypeScript just adds the type guard.

Answer (score 11):

Typescript has introduced some new features that make this easier since the accepted answer was published. Here's now I would do this in 2020 as of Typescript 3.8.3:

```js
const myTypes = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Thing'] as const;
type MyType = typeof myType[number]; // 'Foo' | 'Bar' | 'Thing'

// Return a typed MyType if string is valid (else throw).
function getMyType(maybeMyType: string): MyType {
    const myType = myTypes.find((validType) => validType === maybeMyType);
    if (myType) {
        return myType;
    }
    throw new Error(`String "${maybeMyType}" is not of type MyType.`);
}

// Use it like this:
const definitelyMyType = getMyType('Foo');
```

Or if you prefer the less-safe-but-arguably-more-readable custom type guard style you could do it like this:

```js
// Define a custom type guard to validate & assert that maybeMyType is MyType.
function isMyType(maybeMyType: string): maybeMyType is MyType {
    return myTypes.includes(maybeMyType);
}

// Use it like this:
const maybeMyType = 'Foo';
if (isMyType(maybeMyType)) {
    const definitelyMyType: MyType = maybeMyType;
}
```

Comment: I am not clear about how ```IsMyType```  function will work, the ```in``` operator should check array indices and not array values

Comment: if we declare ```myTypes``` array can't we just test with ``` myTypes.includes ``` since we have to use the guard function in any case, having to implement a guard function actually defeats the purpose of declaring a type

Comment: @SuryaPratap the usage of `in` was my error. Fixed.

Comment: @SuryaPratap You can use `myTypes.includes` to check if a variable has a certain type, but the TS compiler won't know about it without the type guard.