# Is there a way to check if a string is included in a Union type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type Foo = "Foo" | "Bar" | "Baz"

function isInFoo(str: string) boolean {
    // return Foo.contains(str); ?
}
```

In typescript, is there an elegant way to check if `str` is in type `Foo`?

Comment: This question and its answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378904/can-i-check-a-type-against-a-union-type-in-typescript

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820587/3333878

Answer (score 5):

Type annotations are removed from compiled code and are not available at runtime. But to expand on Ivan's answer, here is an example of extracting typed data from an array:

```js
const fooBar = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;
type FooBar = typeof fooBar[number]; // "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
```

Then you can write a custom type guard that checks a string at runtime:

```js
function isFooBar(string: unknown): string is FooBar {
    return typeof string === 'string' && string in fooBar;
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
const maybeFooBar: unknown = 'baz';
if (isFooBar(maybeFooBar)) {
    console.log('Typescript knows this is a FooBar');
}
```

Comment: I added a more in-depth answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129291/3076390

Comment: isFooBar will return false since `string in fooBar` will return false as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#examples

Comment: @Clanket is correct here, the `in` operator checks for the existence of keys, not values. So `0 in fooBar`, `1 in fooBar`, `2 in fooBar` will return `true`, but `string in fooBar` will always return `false` if `typeof string === 'string'` is `true`

Answer (score 1):

***type*** **Foo** will not be compiled into the generated javascript. It can not be realized in an elegant way. As one option: use an array with the specified strings, or get at these fields through an enum.