# Parsing string literals into enum array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, json-deserialization

I'm receiving the following in an API response:

```
{ "roles": [ "ADMIN", "USER" ] }
```

where the response will always contain an array of roles (`USER`, `PRESENTER`, `ORGANIZER`, and `ADMIN`).

I want to convert it into a valid TypeScript array (`Role[]`), where the type `Role` is defined as follows:

```
export type Role = 'USER' | 'PRESENTER' | 'ORGANIZER' | 'ADMIN'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: from where `presenter` & `organizer` came into picture? ALso the expected output is not clear

Comment: If you are looking for speedup using `Symbol`s would be a good idea

Comment: No, I just want to parse the string received into a valid enum.

Comment: @Sammy What purpose do you want to serve with this, exactly?

Comment: @Victor I have an API that will only take `Role[]` as input.

Comment: Are you just looking to cast the response type to be a `Role[]`? Is there an issue with using the usual cast using `as`? EG, something like `const roles = response.roles as Role[]`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put an assertion in there to let TypeScript know about the type? i.e. `as Role[]`

Comment: Thank you @DanielWStrimpel! This did it: `const roles = (response.roles) as any[];`

Comment: That's no enum. There are [string type enums in TypeScript now](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), but that's not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Role` type is *not* an enum.  It is just a string type limited to certain values.

You can just cast the result as a `Role[]` and TypeScript will be happy.  This assumes the incoming data never has a bad value!

```
const data: {roles: Role[]} = JSON.parse('{"roles": ["ADMIN", "USER"]}');
data.roles // TypeScript knows it is a Role[]
```

Comment: And if data might have bad input, just run an `if` and you're done :)

Comment: @Victor: But coding that `if` in an extensible way is tricky.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but there's no other way than having a model to validate inputs from an API. Another way is using a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) which will handle the `if`s for you

Comment: @Victor: Not sure what you mean by "no other way" given [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027123/157247).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* just cast it to your union type:

```
const apiRoleArray = ["ADMIN", "USER"];
const realRoleArray: Role[] = <Role[]>apiRoleArray;
```

**BUT** you probably want to validate its contents rather than just trusting the API. :-) Drawing on [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836011/checking-validity-of-string-literal-union-type-at-runtime), you can create the type by using the keys of an object rather than defining it literally (see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621735/157247) there for why):

```
const roleStrings = {
    USER: "",
    PRESENTER: "",
    ORGANIZER: "",
    ADMIN: ""
};

export type Role = keyof typeof roleStrings;
```

then give yourself a validation function:

```
const isRole = (s: string): s is Role => {
    return roleStrings.hasOwnProperty(s);
};
```

then a robust conversion function, for example:

```
const rawToRoleArray = (rawArray: string[]): Role[] => {
    return rawArray.map(s => {
        if (!isRole(s)) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Role: " + s);
        }
        return <Role>s;
    });
};
```

(you could combine those if you don't need them separately)

then use it:

```
// Valid
const realRoleArray: Role[] = rawToRoleArray(["ADMIN", "USER"]); 
console.log(realRoleArray);
// Invalid
const realRoleArray2: Role[] = rawToRoleArray(["ADMIN", "FOO"]); 
console.log(realRoleArray2);
```

[Live in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20roleStrings%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20USER%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PRESENTER%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ORGANIZER%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ADMIN%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Role%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20roleStrings%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isRole%20%3D%20(s%3A%20string)%3A%20s%20is%20Role%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20roleStrings.hasOwnProperty(s)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20rawToRoleArray%20%3D%20(rawArray%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20Role%5B%5D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20rawArray.map(s%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!isRole(s))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Invalid%20Role%3A%20%22%20%2B%20s)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CRole%3Es%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Valid%0D%0Aconst%20realRoleArray%3A%20Role%5B%5D%20%3D%20rawToRoleArray(%5B%22ADMIN%22%2C%20%22USER%22%5D)%3B%20%0D%0Aconsole.log(realRoleArray)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Invalid%0D%0Aconst%20realRoleArray2%3A%20Role%5B%5D%20%3D%20rawToRoleArray(%5B%22ADMIN%22%2C%20%22FOO%22%5D)%3B%20%0D%0Aconsole.log(realRoleArray2)%3B) | [Live on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uej3e2fz/)

Comment: Here's the `if` I was talking about: `if (!isRole(s))`.

Comment: I appreciate that, yeah. It is important!

Comment: this is definitely the better answer if you do not trust the values coming from the API, or want to code defensively against future changes to the API contract.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you corectly thats what you want to do.

```
enum RoleEnum {
  USER,
  PRESENTER,
  ORGANIZER,
  ADMIN
}

const parseEnum = (name: String): RoleEnum  => RoleEnum[`${name}`]

const parsed: RoleEnum[] = [ 'ADMIN', 'USER' ].map(parseEnum)

console.log(parsed)
```