# typescript - using String Literal Types to check string in runtime

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I have the following type defined in typescript

```js
export type Unit =
    | 'year'
    | 'month'
    | 'day'
    | 'hour'
    | 'minute'
    | 'second'
    | 'millisecond'
```

Is there a way to check a string if that string matches any of the above types using **typescript**?

```js
const x = 'abc'

x "typeOf" Unit => false?
```

EDIT: Found anwser, have marked question as duplicate

[Checking validity of string literal union type at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836011/checking-validity-of-string-literal-union-type-at-runtime)

Comment: check in runtime?

Comment: yes that would be my goal

Comment: then you should look away [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), because [types are stripped away at compile-time and do not exist at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Comment: @HanChe do you control creation of type `Unit` or it comes from 3rd party?

Comment: Found the anwser in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836011/checking-validity-of-string-literal-union-type-at-runtime

Comment: If the definition of the type is in your hands - you can create array of valid unit values, then create a `Unit` type from it

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgOQJIBUDKMC8MDaByATwFMBDAJzwBoY8BbcKACypoBMSCW9GQBXC6nQCWYXlCJcIRUGFZdaQgDaKhUmXIC6MEhBgzoAbgCwAKFNQCAByLwwQ2NgvWQAM3jJ0OUbQBGRMhoGMAD0wTAARMTk4TAAPhH0YEwx8eHsBCkRPPyZ4Qqi4rlq4Ky5Csqq0iXhpqb6sKpwdg4wABS8AFzaYAQAlF28MKq29lgAfO6oaAB0IqxEAB4A8i7tvTAAhJjYALQAjAZAA

Comment: Oh, did not think about it, nice solution :)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Cool solution! Could you explain quickly the `typeof UNITS[number]`? How does typeof convert array to a type and what does the `[number]` do?

Comment: @HanChe `typeof` operator allows to query the type of variable (value). so `typeof UNITS` is tuple `['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'millisecond']`. Now `[number]` part is "index access operator" at type level - returns type of tuple/array member (which is union of all valid tuple members) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376468/how-to-get-type-of-array-items/46387055#46387055

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820587/3333878